# firestore security rules : deny profile update but allow rating update

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I have collection called 'services' inside every document I have 4 fields :

- name
- description
- userID
- Rating

and I want to give only the user to change his profile except rating I want to make it accessible (can update) to everyone , I check some problem like that and I get one solution that is create sub collection  in profile doc I call it "rating" that contain a doc with the name "rate" and I make only this sub collection accessible to update from everyone ,
but I don't know how to  to get subcollection data from a doc  any solution plz with this rating problem :

My security rules after creation a sub collection for rating  :

```
 match /{category}/{serviceid} {
   allow read,create;
   allow update : if resource.data.userID == request.auth.uid;
   match /rating/rate {
     allow read,write;
   }
 }
```

I get all services with `const docs =db.collection("categoryname").get()` :
and I fetch every item data like that :
`docs.foreach(doc => doc.data().name)`
How can I get subcollection("rating") data from the doc?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You realize that with these rules, you allow everyone access? Even people unauthenticated would be able to make unlimited writes. Is that what you really want?

To answer your question, to access to the `/rating/rate` document you could just do:

```
let category = "categoryname";
db.collection(category).get()
.then(function(querySnapshot) {
  querySnapshot.foreach(
    function(doc) {
      let serviceid = doc.id;
      db.collection(category).doc(serviceid).collection("rating").doc("rate").get()
      .then(function(doc) {
        ... // do whatever
      }
    }
  )
}
```

You can also check the [Official Documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data#get_a_document) to get a document.

Comment: thanks bro , Im already solve my problem with the same way as your solution , I create a function that fetch my rate doc because Im using flatlist and I want rate doc for every service item , thanks